Textile Innovations of Pachyderms: Clothing Type
I've developed a race of elephant-centaurs (imagine humanoid elephants with the body of an elephant where their legs should be). They are 8 metres tall from head to toes.
For now, I am working on clothing them, but I'm having issues figuring out what would be realistic. I was thinking that the 'standard' item of clothing would be a single sheet of cloth to be wrapped around the upper body, but I'm not sure how much sense that would make. Besides, they would also need something for their elephantine lower half, and I have zero ideas on how that could be achieved.
So essentially, what would be some 'realistic' clothes for them? They inhabit a region with coastal tropical rainforests to the North, woodlands, grasslands, and savannas to the East, West, and center. They receive an average of 800 mm of precipitations per year, and the average temperature is around 22°C. They have Iron Age levels of technology. Further information can be found on my previous question (except for the caloric intake - that's incorrect.)
Edit: They weigh around 5.7 metric tons.

What is the primary purpose of this clothing? Modesty, protection from injury, sun protection, thermoregulation, fashion, hygiene, comfort, or ability to carry things?

@Mathaddict Modesty, but sun protection and thermoregulation are also needed.

If you have the body size you describe, your main problem is shedding away all your body heat. Clothes is the last thing you want to wear!
You elepha-ntaurs would go around in the naked, because that's what works best in keeping cool and not overheating. Being about 4 times the size of a human, they will have $4^3=64$ times the mass producing heat and only $4^2=16$ times the surface to expell it. This means that even what for a human is an diddly-do action, for them will be a sweaty one.
Why do you think real elephants enjoy so much playing in water every time they can?

Fun fact: Elephants have very few sweat glands, located on the cuticle around their toe nails. Elephants skin is completely dry.

@AlexP That's why they have so many blood vessels in their ears, giant bio-radiators.

None.
Humans in the tropics wear almost nothing and your elephantuars have to shed far more heat per unit skin surface. The cubed-squared law is not kind to heat dissipation. On top of that an average of 22°C means that the days are warmer, probably quite a bit warmer, and at night you have shelters and fire to create extra warmth if needed. So clothing is not necessary, in fact it could be dangerous, especially if they're doing hard physical labour. I would not want to be a blacksmith for these guys, it's warm enough swinging a hammer at the hearthside when its only about 10°C, and I have an outdoor forge hearth too. Field workers etc... may even need to be backed up by attendants with coolant sprayers and salt-ice blocks for them to consume during regular breaks.

...I don't think they'd be able to have coolant sprayers due to the Iron Age thing, but uh... what do you mean by salt-ice blocks? I've looked up the term and I couldn't find anything.

@DuskForm If they have trunks they can spray themselves, or just have a bucket brigade, cool off and irrigate all at once. Iceblocks made from water with some sugar and salt added, (final composition is similar to what goes in a glucose saline drip) harder to freeze but they're better for you if you're sweating than straight water.

@Ash sugar? there was no sugar in the iron age, it's something that came up at renaissance or even later. Perhaps some sweet fruits could be used instead, but to unknown side effects.

@Vesper Sugarcane outside it's native range sure (and purified sugar in general), but honey, agave, and malt are all much older discoveries, beet sugar was developed long after it was technically possible to produce it, different history, different results.

Other answers have sufficiently introduced the heat dissipation issues facing large animals. I propose that any clothing worn by elephant-shaped creatures with human intelligence would be designed to specifically address heat dissipation. Clothing as a technology is more about practicality and function the further back in history you look, so this clothing would be no different.
Basically, imagine the opposite of a stillsuit in Dune. The idea would be to use your clothing to facilitate water evaporation.
Shawls made of particularly absorbent fabric would help elephants stay cool long after visiting a watering hole. Surface area would be another important consideration when designing clothing that evaporates water. One could imagine fashion evolving around ruffs and other high fold-count articles of clothing.
Edit: More generally, heat dissipation is the goal, not just water evaporation. So again, the high surface area would be useful.

They would only need clothing for modesties sake. So it would make most sense to have a harness rather than full blown clothing. Or perhaps a loin cloth, or some sort of combination. A harness makes more sense as it needs to be something they can put on themselves.
If they have human sensibilities they'd cover their groin and anus. Not much else is necessary. My society wears a skirt type garment, and it's perfectly acceptable to wear nothing else most of the time. Others wear a loin cloth in the tropics.

...what do you mean by 'harness'?

Harness like an animals, straps with appended bits and pieces. Something that you could put on and off without gymnastics. I don't even see how you'd put any sort of wraparound on the lower half, but a harness would be easy.

"Modesty" is a difficult problem in elephants. An male African elephant's penis is about 5 feet (1.5 meters) long when extended, can be extended and retracted at will, and the elephant can and frequently does use it as an additonal support.

@DuskForm, something along the lines of a utility belt: plenty of pockets and loops for holding things.

There have been plenty of answers about elephants and heat dissipation. Many comments have covered ideas like modesty as well. The other element I'd recommend considering is how these elephantaurs are carrying everyday objects.
Do they carry objects on their back? Do they use ties (like we do for our cars) or something like saddlebags (that they'd drape over their back)? Are they able to reach down with their human hands and pick objects off the ground, or would they need some technology in place of the elephant's trunk? I imagine most of their clothing would be purely functional, since clothing would otherwise inhibit their ability to cool off.
The exception is for the part of them that's human. You often see other creatures like this (Driders from D&D, for example) wearing human clothing from the waist up. If their human skin is different from the elephant skin, then they might need forms of protection against the sun, etc. Other answers have answered this more clearly.

HATS, UMBRELLAS and TENTS
They will want to cover as much as possible from the sun BUT not keep things on-skin for the various reasons the other users already stated.
Depending on how dexterous they are, and how much they can turn their humanoid torso toward their 'taur(?) back they might actually lodge a whole curtain\tent on their back: at their size it would probably feel not much more than a relatively light backpack for us(though I guess that would depend on the available materials) while keeping them shielded from the direct sun.
Depending on societal structure(and how much they can turn back) the fanciness of the "tent" might reflect their social status: one big\complex enough to require attendants to be worn means wealth, while poor people would be limited to simpler\smaller ones, even just the aforementioned hats or umbrellas.
The textile innovations would thus involve thermal isolation and in second base, breathability... in short, well, tent-making. Which is something I know nothing of.
